# How do I wrap and set CSS properties to achieve the depicted results?

Tags: css

I'm developing a web application that in a view has three panels as the image shows:

[image]

Which CSS properties would you use to have the bottom panel get the same width as the upper two panels combined in a dynamic context?

**EDIT:** I'm sorry I should have mentioned that **I can't use any javascript**. I need a solution purely executed by CSS. The markup is generated from the java code of which I'm developing the application so I don't have a direct access to that either.

Comment: Use javascript or jquery

Comment: this is vulnerable! it is very difficult to explain. i have many ideas to work with such scenario's but we cannot explain, we cannot create the layouts for you.

Comment: You just edited that your markup can't be changed. Could you please post your exact markup? Maybe your layout isn't even possible if some requirements aren't fulfilled.

Comment: @Zeta I'm trying to integrate the CSS from the proposal you posted. And yes I have close to no control over the divs that are generated. Posting the markup would only scare people away, a layout as simple as this could probably consist of about 30 tags using this framework. it's a pain.. =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn about `display:inline-block;`, `float`, `position` and other properties for display and positioning options. I just guess there's something like a wrapper.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="firstPanel">First panel <br/>width: 300px</div>
    <div id="secondPanel">
         Second panel <br/> width: > 300px, thus min-width:300px;
    </div>
    <div id="thirdPanel">
         Third panel. <br/> width: First panel + second panel + margin(?)
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
    /* a block element will take all width, so you have to use a specific width,
    a floating or an inline element.*/
}
#wrapper > div{ /* just for convenience */
    border:1px solid #000; 
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:.2em;
}
#firstPanel, #secondPanel{
    /* to show both in the same row. float:left is also possible */
    display:inline-block;
}
#firstPanel{width:300px;}
#secondPanel{min-width:300px;}

/* if you use float:left above, you have to use */
#thirdPanel{clear:both;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xqwfL/1/)

Comment: I was looking for that, forgot about `inline-block`. Great answer.

Comment: I see from the demo that this definitely is the correct answer for producing the layout I'm after. Unfortunately I can't apply it to my environment due to "restrictions" in the framework. I've battled this problem long enough now (stretching over two weeks) and I can't see that an answer suitable for my needs will be presented here, I'll have to do it another way. I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score -1):

get the width of your second panel and add the fixed width of your first panel to it and apply it to your third div

```
var secondPanel = $('.secondPanel').width();
secondPanel = parseInt(secondPanel.substr(0,secondPanel.length-2));
secondPanel = secondPanel + 300;
$('.thirdPanel').css('width',secondPanel);
```

try this code, its with jquery

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:css], the OP has also stated he wishes to use CSS, and not JavaScript. "I want to kill someone with my bare hands, teach me Karate!" ~"Use a gun".

Comment: @palsingh thanks Pal for your answer. I'm sorry I forgot to mention in the question that I can't make use of javascript, I need a solution purely executed by CSS.

Comment: @Truth he had edited the question after i posted the answer, before doing negative to the answer, you should know what you are doing ok X-(

Comment: @palsingh hey Pal I didn't vote your question down. It's my error that I didn't communicate more thoroughly what type of solution I was after. I'll vote it up for you, definitely doesn't deserve a -1 IMO.

Comment: @palsingh: The edit he made doesn't change my point. The question itself is tagged [tag:css] and not [tag:javascript] or [tag:jquery], he also asked about "CSS properties" to use, before he edited the question. Hence, my downvote still stands.